# Python binary diff

Tags: python, diff

I'm trying to use bsdiff (or any binary diff implementation you come up with) to compute and apply diff onto random binary data. I would like to use it on data from a database, so it would be better not to have to write those onto disk and pass them to bsdiff.exe.

Is there any wrapper library or way in python to do that?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/ilanschnell/bsdiff4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) website:

> It has also been made into a [Python extension module](http://starship.python.net/crew/atuining/cx_bsdiff/index.html), and there is a Windows port available.

Following the link brings you to the module's page.

Comment: I somehow saw the Windows link but not this one...
There's no version for 2.6 but it can't be that hard to build for it, am I right?

Comment: Probably isn't hard.  Definitely worth trying.

Comment: python setup.py install just does'nt work, gives me "failed with exit status 1107".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) that is part of Python standard library. You can send any arbitrary data into a `difflib.SequenceMatcher`.

Comment: difflib seems to be made for text files, returning the diff between the lines.

Comment: not true. You can send any arbitrary data into a SequenceMatcher.

Comment: difflib is horrifically slow for largeish (~4MB) blocks of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the `SequenceMatcher` class (from the Python standard library) can be helpful.

Check out the other contents of the `difflib` module as well.